Импорт модулей в папке
Вот структура проекта:

Мне надо в модуле First.py импортировать модуль Second.py, но вылезает ошибка.
Код с которым я пытался
main.py
import Folder.First

Folder.First.Hello_world()

First.py
import Second

def Hello_world():
    return "Hello " + Second.world

Second.py
world = "World"

И Вот ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<Имя пользователя>\PycharmProjects\Stack\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Folder.First
  File "C:\Users\<Имя пользователя>\PycharmProjects\Stack\Folder\First.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Second
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Second'



from . import Second

В качестве совета: я избавился от этих глупостей с компоновкой самого первого дня программирования в Питоне. Видите на картинке Ваши три файла? И я вижу. Объединять файлы в один умеете? И я умею. Объединили в один файл в таком порядке: first.py, second.py, main.py и никаких импортов ВООБЩЕ не требуется. Конечно, в первых двух теперь должны появиться def first(): и def second(): или нет, если используются просто внутренние функции, но это уже мелочи.
У меня не бывает таких "сюрпризов". Ведь я сам файлы собираю в финальный модуль, так, как я захочу.

@FoxFox я так понимаю, первый день программирования на питоне был у вас не так давно? иначе как объяснить вашу тягу давать вредные советы?

Я кому-то что-то навязываю? Я написал ясно и внятно: я советую, Я так делаю. У меня проблем нет. И совет этот ПОЛЕЗНЫЙ. Я просто руками делаю точно то же, что и "искусственный разум". Всё в конечном счёте заканчивается в обоих случаях компилированным исполняемым файлом. Просто у меня гемора с компоновкой нет. Если кому-то гемор нравится, кто ж запретит? Вот это исполнение задрипанных теорий в книжках любой ценой нравится мне особенно. Я своей головой умею думать. Особенно там, где касается несчастных файловых операций, сложность которых выеденного яйца не стоит.

Стаж программирования - 31 год. Если не считать программирования на калькуляторе МК-61 математических задач в университете. Это моё поколение создавало Python. Мы умели и умеем думать головой.

@FoxFox судя по тому, как и сколько вы пишите, лично вы в создании python участия не принимали. в общем, "горшочек, не вари!".

Я способен думать над той чушью, которую пишут в книжках. И я не беру из них всё подряд. В частности, когда я увидел на пяти страницах эпопею о написанном на Питоне менеджере сборки кода и танцах вокруг неё, меня охватила ржачка.  Через пятнадцать минут я написал свой "менеджер сборки". И избавился раз и навсегда от "сюрпризов", заодно и от лишней писанины. То же касается и ttk. Два часа и свой. Есть разница между инженером и электриком. Инженер спрашивает, почему так, почему нельзя проще. Электрик не способен, всегда исполняет. Я - инженер. Я думаю, как сделать проще.

Вот решение которое мне помогло:
Было
import Second

Стало
from . import Second

За решение спасибо @andreymal
